# Fixing insdside window sill heights to match

Tags: windows

I have 3 windows that i'm trying to match sill heights on.  This is like a bay window (not a true bay window because it's 3 separate windows).  I cut all 3 window sills with returns but I wanted to match all the sills making the appearance of one continuous sill (if that makes sense).  The problem I ran into is all 3 windows are at different levels.  The smaller left window is almost 1/4" higher than the bigger middle window and the middle window is about 1/8" higher than the smaller right window.  So just to clarify, the returns on each sill will butt up to each other (if I can fix the height problem).  Can anyone help with solutions to fix this?

Comment: While a picture would help, I would think that the sill and the trim could be adjusted to cover that small of a variation.  You will end up with a gap under the sill on the lower windows and a trim would cover that gap.

Comment: My reply would be diff. depending on: type of windows (casement vs double-hung), how they operate (inward v. outward swing casement), and if they're traditional (single pane, all wood) vs contemporary (double pane, alum.,vinyl).  It would also make a diff. if you're speaking of exterior sill or interior stool and whether or not the stool extends into the frame of the window (covering the interior part of the window frame that forms the exterior sill).

Comment: They are double-hung vinyl windows.  I am talking about the interior stool.  They do have a pre-finished "casement" that were on the windows upon installation.  My goal is to extend the sill so that they have a return into the wall for the vertical trim to sit on.  I can't get a pic right now but here is an example of the rough in framing and the window units themselves.http://www.foxcustomhomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/bay-window-framing.jpg

Comment: Here is what i'm going for "ish".  The returns hopefully will connect with each other.

Comment: http://www.changingcurtains.co.uk/images/curtains/curtains%20on%20poles/william%20morris%20on%20bay%20pole%20open%20L.jpg    This isn't the best pic to show, but its close to what im going for.  Again the whole issue is the heights of the windows themselves.  I hope this helps to clarify the problem and goal.  Thanks in advance.